# Update all documents in collection atomically. What if one of them changes during the transaction?

Tags: mongodb, transactions, atomic

I'm trying to perform a Mongo transaction that will update all documents in a collection. The problem is that the documents change extremely frequently (say multiple times per second) and I risk sometimes not being able to do commit the transaction because one document changed.

I could retry after this happens, but what if at least one document keeps changing every time I retry?

Then the transaction will just keep retrying and never be committed.

How do I update atomically if the documents in the collection keep changing while the update is taking place?

I'm thinking that this is a pretty common problem and there must be a good solution, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: In general, there should be relatively few situations where it's necessary to do an all-at-once collection migration rather than doing an incremental migration. Without an explicitly fixed schema, the general pattern is to set up your application code to handle 2 versions of a document (old or new), incrementally migrate all of your documents, and then remove the application code that handles the older documents. What's the update that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Imagine there's a bunch of players in a game, and these players get rewards every 5 minutes based on the zone they are in. The rewards are unique to each zone and get deleted when the player leaves the zone. At time t_0, 500 of these players are in zone 1, so I add the rewards to these players atomically. The transaction completes at time t_1. But what if one of these players leave the zone while the transaction is in place (e.g. between t_0 and t_1)? Then he will have a reward that he shouldn't have (and would have been deleted otherwise).

Comment: Interesting! My first instinct would be to include the zone information on the created reward so that application code can filter out any invalid rewards. Another option might be to only store `zoneEnteredTime` on the player & calculate the full list of rewards from that. I'm sure there's a way of doing what you're looking for, but I'm definitely not sure how to do it.